# SQL Server error: " Incorrect syntax near 'seem'. "

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use this query to Find a string in a database, but I got this error for a particular DB:

> Incorrect syntax near 'seem'.

So I would like to know the reason for that

```
CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630)) 

SET NOCOUNT ON 

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110) 

SET @TableName = '' 

SET @SearchStr2 = quotename( '%NQF%0028a%' , '''' ) 

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
   SET @ColumnName = '' 
   SET @TableName = 

   (
     SELECT min(quotename(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + quotename(TABLE_NAME)) 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
       AND quotename(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + quotename(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName 
       AND objectproperty(object_id(quotename(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + quotename(TABLE_NAME)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0 
   ) 

   WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL) 
   BEGIN 
      SET @ColumnName = (SELECT min(quotename(COLUMN_NAME)) 
                         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                         WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = parsename(@TableName, 2) 
                           AND TABLE_NAME = parsename(@TableName, 1) 
                           AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar') 
                           AND quotename(COLUMN_NAME ) > @ColumnName ) 

      IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL 
      BEGIN 
          INSERT INTO #Results 
            EXEC 
             ('SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630)    
    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' + 

    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2 

) 

END 

END 

END 


SELECT ColumnName , ColumnValue FROM #Results**strong text**
```

Comment: Please explain your problem clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your have a space in your table name. Check the table that has "SEEM" as part of it's name and remove the space, if possible. If change of table name is not an option, wrap the `@TableName` variable in `[]`

Comment: It would be better to recommend [`QUOTENAME`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) since that also deals with other nasties, such as table names that contain `]` characters.